# Android bluetooth crashing when normal, but not in debug

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to add bluetooth to my app. I made sure everything is initialized and everything works, but when I run the app normally, it says that one view or another is null, but when I run it in debug it works normally, any idea why this is caused or how to fix it?